# How to export field values from a struct to another struct in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, struct, matlab-struct

I have a struct of 283 Area values and I want to copy the higher than 1000 values to a second struct with a for function. I have writen the code I need like this

```
Lbp = regionprops(Lblack, 'Area');
Lbp.Area;
[r,c]=size(Lbp);

B(r,c) = struct();


for d=1:r
    for g=1:c
          if Lbp(d).Area > 1000
              i=1;
              B(i)=Lbp(d);
              i=i+1;
          end
    end
end
```

I am getting this error **Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures.** Even though the structs are the same size. I know that my syntax is wrong but I can not figure out how to syntax it in order to copy the fields to the second struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `B` and `Lbp` do not have the same fields. Try the following:

```
B(r,c) = struct('Area',[]);
```

Comment: @Kate It works. Maybe you didn't clear `B` from your workspace before entering `B(r,c) = struct('Area',[]);`. If `B(r,c) = struct();` is still in memory, then you will get the same error as before. Try `clear B` first and then try again.

Comment: It only saves the last value. And all the other fields are filled with [].

Comment: @Kate You need to initialize `i` outside of the loops. It is being reset to 1 every iteration.

Comment: Oh my god, yes! It totally slipped my eyes. Thank you!